# How to fix 'TypeError using Threads' in Python

Tags: python, multithreading

My first ZipCracker worked but it just checked Passwords which are in the range from 0 to 2000. I wanted that my ZipCracker could check every Combination and programmed it with Threads, now it doesn't work.

I learn the programming language Python at this time. I want to practice it a little bit. I decided to program a little ZipCracker.

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
from threading import Thread
import zipfile
import string
import itertools

class ZipCracker():

        def __init__(self, filename): 
        self.filename = filename
        self.zipfile = zipfile.ZipFile(filename)
        self.targetdirectory = filename[:-4]

    def test_password(self, password):
        try:
            self.zipfile.extractall(path=self.targetdirectory, pwd =  str.encode(password))
            return True
        except Exception as e:
            return False

    def brute_force(self):

        zipFile = self.targetdirectory
        myLetters = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + string.punctuation
        for i in range(3, 10):
            for j in map(''.join, itertools.product(myLetters, repeat=i)):
                t = Thread(target=ZipCracker.test_password, args=(zipFile, j,))
                password = str(j)
                print password
                t.start()

            if self.ZipCracker.test_password(password):
                print("Erfolg: " + password)
                return password

        return None
```

I expect that the output is that every possibility should be showed and it should stop when the right password is there, but the actual output is the following Error:

```
Exception in thread Thread-6152:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 763, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
TypeError: unbound method test_password() must be called with ZipCracker instance as first argument (got str instance instead)
```

Comment: use button `{}` to correctly format code and error message

Comment: inside class `ZipCracker` you have to `self.` instead of `self.ZipCracker`

Comment: you will have problem with `target=ZipCracker.test_password, args=(zipFile, j,)` because (1) `test_password` need instance of `ZipCracker` (2) your arguments are for class constructor but they will be used as `test_password(zipFile, j)`. Better create functio which create instance of `ZipCracker` and run `test_password` and use this function in `Thread(target=your_function)`

Comment: First I want to say thank you, that you took your time to help me. An other question now, could you help me a little bit with my Problem target=ZipCracker.test_password, args=(zipFile, j,) this. I don't know how to do that what you sad.

Comment: `Thread(target=self.test_password, args=(j,))`

Comment: Thank you again. It works, but it doesn't stop on the right point, I mean that it doesn't stop and don't show the right Password. Could you help me with this Problem?

Comment: if you have new problem then create new question on new page. You will have more space to show error and describe it. Maybe other people will also read new question. You could also add some example zip with simple password so people could run it and see problem.